# Flow3-Fluid iterate object grouped by property

Tags: for-loop, fluid, typo3-flow

I've a list of objects (question-items), each with a property named category and title.
(The list of objects is ordered by its category property)

With this Fluid Template I want to iterate over the question items:

```
<f:for each="{questions}" as="question">
   <!-- every time category changes, display it as a new headline ??? -->
   <!-- if (question.category != previousQuestion.category) ?.....? -->
   <span>{question.title}</span>
</f:for>
```

How can I check, if the category property has changed in the for?
The output should be something like this:

- Category-A

  - Question
  - Question
- Category-B

  - Question
- Category-C

  - Question
  - Question
  - Question
  - ...

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the f:groupedFor viewhelper: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/GroupedFor.html

```xml
<f:groupedFor each="{questions}" as="categoryQuestion" groupBy="category" groupKey="category">
    <h2>{category}</h2>
    <f:for each="{categoryQuestion}" as="question">
        <span>{question.title}</span>
    </f:for>
</f:groupedFor>
```

Your approach with the `<f:if>` viewhelper won't work, because there are no real template-variables in fluid, just xml-scoped "constants", so even if you define previousQuestion via the `<f:alias>` viewhelper, you wouldn't be able to compare it to the current value.